# Percentage of one point composed by two other points

Tags: geometry

I have a question to calculate the percentage of point $c$ in $c_1$ and $c_2$ points.

$c$ is located on a straight line between $c_1$ and $c_2$. The coordinates are real numbers. (The coordinates represent an RGB color, but it doesn't matter for the geometry aspect of the question.)

The answer to that question uses the distance formula: $$d(c,c_1) = [(x_0-x_1)^2+(y_0-y_1)^2])]^{1/2},$$

and the percentage $p_1$ (which is $c_1$ in $c$) is as follows:

$$P1 = (d(c_1,c_2) - d(c,c_1))/d(c_1,c_2) * 100.$$

Which obviously derived from:

$$(d(c_1,c_2)*p_1)/100 = d(c_1,c_2) - d(c,c_1).$$

The last equation means that $p_1$ is a percentage from the distance of $c_1-c_2$ which equals to the difference between the distances of $c_1-c_2$ and $c-c_1$ (= the distance of $c-c_2$).

A. I am lacking the intuition here, why are we looking at the distance between the point $c_1$ and $c_2$ in order to find the  the percentage of $c$ from $C_1$ ?

B. Why the percentage $P_1$ is equal to the distance of $c-c_2$, shouldn't it be maybe equal to the distance of $c-c_1$ by intuition ? (intuition can be wrong, but something is bothering me about it and I am looking for clarification)

I am sorry about the lack of symbols, I haven't figure out how to add them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(A)** Suppose $d(c,c_1)=1$.

If the whole line segment $d(c_1,c_2)=2$ then point $c$ is right in the middle, so the color is the "average" (how it is implemented is a different matter).

If $d(c_1,c_2)=100~$ or $~d(c_1,c_2)=200~$ or just some large number, then point $c$ is very close to the endpoint $c_1$, meaning the color of $c$ should be basically just the color of $c_1$. (unless I misunderstand the scenario)

This consideration of the above two cases with the same $d(c,c_1)$ demonstrates that we also need the total length.

**(B)** Continuing the example above, when point $c$ is close to $c_1$, which distance is larger? Is it $d(c,c_1)~$ or $~d(c,c_2)$? Assuming we want the percentage $P_1$ to be larger to reflect the fact that $c$ is closer to $c_1$, then $P_1$ should be proportional to larger distance, which is $d(c,c_2)$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it is correct now. Is there an intuition to how they reached the distinction that (1,2)−(,1) represent correctly the proportion of c from c1 ? I understand this when I am checking example cases but not from the equation itself.

Comment: By definition $d(c, c_2) = d(c_1, c_2) - d(c,c_1)$, namely, "the latter segment equals whole segment minus the first segment". Does this answer your question? Or are you asking something else like "why don't we use the square or other powers of the length?"

Comment: I asked it wrong. It is difficult for me to see the intuition, how did they reach the fact that P1 is ((1,2)−(,1))/(1,2) ? . I understand it from the example cases, but not the intuition on how to get there myself.

Comment: The intuition is a physical one. Consider a metal rod of uniform thickness and density (as in density for weight). The longer the rod the heavier it is, and the weight is directly (linearly) proportional to the length. Namely, if the rod is cut down to a third of its original length, then the weight also becomes exactly a third of its original weight. Last but not least, in this application for the color, the linear dependency is not a "fact" but a model that people can choose to adopt or not adopt.